# How to convert date format when reading from Excel - Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, type-conversion, datetime-format

I am reading from an Excel sheet. The header is date in the format of Month-Year and I want to keep it that way. But when it reades it, it changes the format to "2014-01-01 00:00:00". I wrote the following peice to fix it, but doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date
import time
file_loc = "path.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], parse_cols = 37)
df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%b-%y')
```

Which didn't do anything. On another try, I did the following:

`df.columns = datetime.datetime.strptime(df.columns, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b-%y')`

Which returns the `must be str, not datetime.datetime` error. I don't know how make it read the row cell by cell to read the strings!

Here is a sample data:

```
NaT 11/14/2015 00:00:00 12/15/2015 00:00:00 1/15/2016 00:00:00
A   5                   1                   6
B   6                   3                   3
```

My main problem with this is that it does not recognize it as the header, e.g., `df['11/14/2015 00:00:00']` retuns an `keyError`.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Here is a photo to illustrate what I keep geting! Box 6 is the implementation of apply, and box 7 is what my data looks like.

[image]

Comment: @EdChum, I posted the problem with date formating here. Thanks.

Comment: I think because you strip incorrectly: `11/14/2015 00:00:00` should be `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'` but not with `'-'` symbols between month and day

Comment: @Anton Protopopov, I tried it with `/`, but still the error says `must be str, not Index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ["11/14/2015 00:00:00", "11/14/2015 00:10:00", "11/14/2015 00:20:00"]})
df["data"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b-%y'))
```

**EDIT**

If you'd like to work with `df.columns` you could use `map` function:

```
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b-%y'), df1.columns))
```

You need list if you are using python 3.x because it's iterator by default.

Comment: You could use apply method for pd.Series of dataframe

Comment: thanks but it didn't work, I have attached a picture in the question body to show the code and result. The next issue is that my data is not in a column, it is the header.

Comment: So you could convert your `df.columns` to `pd.Series` with `pd.Series(df.columns)` and then use apply method. Look to the last edit

Comment: The `list` worked! I just had to change the inner `x` to `str(x)` to avoid the `must be str, not Timestamp` error. Thansk.

Comment: But the problem is when I print the dataframe, it still displays the old format.

Comment: Because you need to assign results to df.columns. Edited for that

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the data in excel isn't stored in the string format you think it is. Perhaps it is stored as a number, and just displayed as a date string in excel.

Excel sometimes uses milliseconds after an epoch to store dates.
Check what the actual values you see in the `df` array.

What does this show?

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(df)
```

Comment: In the excel, the very first cell is `1/1/2014` and then each cell is `=previous cell +31`. `pprint(df)` prints `2015-11-14 00:00:00`.